# oil light not showing on car

Tags: oil, lights

i drive a toyota tazz 1.3 it has an immobiliser it has been working fine and yesterday i tried to turn it on it didnt show oil light only battery light and didnt start it tried kicking it and it did start however when I drove the car it shut completely I called where I installed my immobilizer to ask if it is connected with my problem they said it does cause it.what might causes a car to do this?

Comment: There are a very wide number of things that can stop a car starting, ranging from battery, starter motor, immobiliser, electrics and so on. Have a look round the site for the questions already here on starting problems.

Comment: Also - you have tagged this with oil and lights - but the problem is a failure to start. To get the best response you should use tags that match your question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this thing called a tazz but it's pretty typical for some warning lights to remain lit when the ignition is energized but not running.  Do you have another key for the car?  If so try it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the car fixed it seem the problem was with the relay fuse it needed to be changed.